# AWS CLI importing credentials from CSV doesn't add region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to import AWS credentials from csv file with headers

> User name,Password,Access key ID,Secret access key,Console login link

and using command

```
aws configure import --csv file://myfile.csv --region us-east-1
```

But the region comes back as empty. I tried setting region header in CSV file too but nothing works.

Below is the output of `aws configure list`

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
      profile       deployment_admin              env    ['AWS_PROFILE', 'AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE']
      access_key     ****************.   shared-credentials-file    
      secret_key     ****************.   shared-credentials-file    
      region                <not set>             None    None
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's supported. The `--region` parameter is listed under the **Global Options**, i.e. can be used with all CLI operations.

> **Global Options**
>
> [...]
>
> `--region (string)`
>
> The region to use. Overrides config/env settings.
>
> — [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/import.html)

Usually, you can use it to direct an API call **to** a specific region. Since there is no API call here, it shouldn't do anything.

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/awscli/customizations/configure/importer.py#L103), it seems like the code really only considers the `'User Name'`, `'Access Key ID'`, and `'Secret Access key'` columns in the CSV so there's no sneaky way to add the region.

Comment: That really sucks, I have a GitLab pipeline config file and I need to run tree times `aws configure set` command for access key id, secret acess key and region, if `configure` supported the `--region` flag as users expects it would be very helpful

Comment: @fudo If you're running in a pipeline anyway, just set the `AWS_REGION` environment variable to the region the job is supposed to be running in.